# How to "PUT" json data back to chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I am able to get response from server using "GET" in chrome rest client:
"https:xxxx/nodes/"
But I cannot "PUT" the same thing back to the same url.
It says server error.

Answer (score 1):

The [Chef Server API](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html) is heavily documented at the link I provided. It is mostly RESTful, but there are certain exceptions. The Chef Server is very particular about the various headers and syntaxes you need in the request, especially for things that mutate state.

Comment: It says in the API doc that the only difference of the need for headers between GET and PUT is "Content-Type: application/json". Since GET works for me, I am not sure why PUT doesn't?

Comment: Are you familiar with REST and the difference between GET and PUT?

Comment: Yes I do. But can you give me some suggestions on what to add on header?

Comment: Are you actually sending a **body** with the PUT? PUT expects data - it's not equivalent to GET

Comment: Yes. I send the json file that I get from "GET"

Comment: Have you tried any of the available libraries? Like [@sethvargo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/365738/sethvargo)'s [chef-api](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-api)? Comparing the requests from that API client with the ones that you send might help to find the difference, if you really need an own implementation.

Comment: Boy, that @sethvargo guy sure knows a lot about the Chef Server API :-p. It would be very helpful to see the exact request you are making and the response you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your server must expect such activity or in other words implement Json receiving. You need to know what resource name is for it. Probably you will need to perform POST request. For post request you need to know what resource you are accessing (my_form.aspx for example). Keeping this in mind you also need to have Content-Type: application/json. The json data actually goes as a post request body.

Comment: What do you mean by resource name? In my example, I just follow the Chef server API documentation: GET /nodes/NAME. It works. Then I do: PUT /nodes/NAME {...(data I got from GET)}, it returns server 500 error.

Comment: The resource name here is what comes right after GET